# Which algorithm Rsync uses for delta encoding?

Tags: rsync

Rsync documentation says what "it uses delta encoding when appropriate". But I can't find witch algorithm it uses for delta encoding. I cannot find it from source. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rsync uses a peculiar version of a rolling checksum. Check out [a full description](http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/) for the details.